# How to find the sum of two PaddingValues in Android Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Suppose I have a `PaddingValues A` and `PaddingValues B`. How to find their sum?

I found no method in Android Compose which sum up two PaddingValues. And getting the values of each side padding is more complicated. Because it requires `LayoutDirection` for Horizontal paddings.

I want to render a `LazyColumn` inside a `Scaffold`. `Scaffold` returns `windowsInsets` as `PaddingValues`. I want to add `8.dp` more vertical padding with that `PaddingValues` before appling to the `contentPadding` of the lazycolumn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using this extension function in our projects to do that. I think it's quite common requirement to sum two instances of `PaddingValues`, so I don't get why it's not part of the compose library.

```kotlin
operator fun PaddingValues.plus(other: PaddingValues): PaddingValues = PaddingValues(
    start = this.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr) +
        other.calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr),
    top = this.calculateTopPadding() + other.calculateTopPadding(),
    end = this.calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr) +
        other.calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr),
    bottom = this.calculateBottomPadding() + other.calculateBottomPadding(),
)
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```kotlin
Scaffold { paddingValues ->
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = paddingValues + PaddingValues(vertical = 8.dp),
    ) {}
}
```

You don't need the actual value of `LayoutDirection`, as that will be taken care of when the resulting `PaddingValues` are resolved. And from the [implementation](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/8bfb531bcc16da2aeefb845c18f9748fae069e61:compose/foundation/foundation-layout/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Padding.kt;l=245) of `PaddingValues`:

```kotlin
fun PaddingValues.calculateStartPadding(layoutDirection: LayoutDirection) =
    if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
        calculateLeftPadding(layoutDirection)
    } else {
        calculateRightPadding(layoutDirection)
    }

override fun calculateLeftPadding(layoutDirection: LayoutDirection) =
    if (layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.Ltr) start else end
```

you can see that if you pass `LayoutDirection.Ltr` to `calculateStartPadding`, you get the `start` value, which is essentially what you want. (Same goes for `calculateEndPadding` and `end`).

Answer (score 0):

Modifier.padding is cumulative you can assign `Modifier.padding(vertical=8.dp).padding(paddingValues)`, with each padding modifier total padding on any direction will be increased.

But if you want to see which value returned by PaddingValues you can call

```
val paddingValues = PaddingValues(bottom = 8.dp, top = 12.dp)
val paddingValues2 = PaddingValues(bottom = 8.dp, top = 12.dp)

val bottomSum = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding() + paddingValues2.calculateBottomPadding()
val topSum = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding() + paddingValues2.calculateTopPadding()
```

And some demo to try either of these

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PaddingValuesPrev() {
    val paddingValues = PaddingValues(bottom = 8.dp, top = 12.dp)
    val paddingValues2 = PaddingValues(bottom = 8.dp, top = 12.dp)

    val bottomSum = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding() + paddingValues2.calculateBottomPadding()
    val topSum = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding() + paddingValues2.calculateTopPadding()
    Column {
        Text(text = "Bottom Sum $bottomSum, topSum: $topSum")

        Scaffold { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 40.dp)
                    .padding(paddingValues = paddingValues)
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Green),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(20) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Row $it",
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.Red)
                            .padding(8.dp),
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use `Modifier.padding`. I want to use `contentPadding` for LazyColumn